# Where can I store and retrieve audio files that the users upload in my MERN app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, file

I have a MERN application and I would like to allow users to upload audio files.
From what I heard storing the files directly in the database or directly in a folder inside the app is not the best option.
What I need is a way to allow users to upload the file, generate an URL, and be able to play that file using the URL after.
What is the best way to do such thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Cloudinary. Using their API would allow you upload files and return a URL you can save to your database to use each time you or your users need to access the audio file